# Handle all click methods in one class?

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

Well lets say that I have an app that have like 50-60 buttons all around and I want to handle all click methods inside other package. How could I handle click for package app.test; class one in package app.test.clicks class clicks?

Comment: It's not a good idea. Frankly, drop it. Let each activity handle its own events.

Comment: agreed ... let's not change the nature ... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class which implements OnClickListener,

```
 public class ClickHandler implements OnClickListener

 {
     public void onClick(View v) {

    //This method will be automatically implemented once OnClickListener is implemented. 

     }

 }
```

Now set the onClickistener to your button like this,.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler());
```

And now inside the onClick() just do this,

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId()==R.id.button)
            {
                //your stuff here. 
            } 

    }
```

If you need context object then,try `v.getContext();`. "v" is the parameter form the onClick().

make sure you import the package name of your ClickHandler class into your Activity.

But it would be much better if you had this as an inner class for each Activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HeaderActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.home)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.search)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.list)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.filter)).setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.home:

        Intent home=new Intent(this,HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(home);
        finish();

        break;
    case R.id.search:
        Intent search=new Intent(this,SearchScreen.class);
        startActivity(search);
        finish();
        break;

    case R.id.list:
        Intent list=new Intent(this,ListScreen.class);
        startActivity(list);
        finish();
        break;

    case R.id.filter:
        Intent filter=new Intent(this,FilterScreen.class);
        startActivity(filter);
        finish();
        break;

    default :  break;   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think it will be a great idea to implement. However you need to pass the **Context** to clicks class. From context object you'll be able to get to the control which has been clicked and you can write your logic accordingly.